# Need help in wiring a parallel DAC, BA9221

Tags: parallel, dac

By looking at the data sheet of BA9221 (http://www.synfo.nl/datasheets/BA9221.pdf) it appears to me (rookie here) that some connections are left out from the diagram. And since I have only 2 pieces of this DAC, I am afraid to go about wildly experimenting with it (to avoid its destruction). Hence my posting here looking for some guidance.

[image: An application example from the data sheet]

My questions are these:

1. Do I need hook up Io and the inverted (is there a better name for this pin?) Io to an op-amp for any meaningful use of BA9221?
2. I have an LM358 (I have a few of these) - will that be adequate? If yes, how to hook it up, since the op-amp BA4558 isn't hooked to an external power supply?
3. When I just connect Vcc (+5V) and Vref+ (3V) and Vref-, the voltage between Io and the inverted Io is shown as 10mV (holds steady). Why is that? When I measure the voltage between Io and the ground, it's showing around 1.2V. Similar thing with the inverted Io.
4. In the application example provided, they used 3k resistors. Is that in order to limit the current fed into Vref pins (from the electrical characteristics table, we learn that Iref needs to be between 0.2 and 1.1 mA)?
5. From the same electrical characteristics table, we see that logic input current is rated at 60 uA max. Does that mean I need to limit the current with adequately sized resistors feeding the digital pins? Or does that mean, that the IC will draw max 60uA per pin without the need to limit the current "externally"?
6. The example also calls for -15V but nowhere does it mention anything about +15V. Why would that be (for some reason, I am expecting a symmetry of sorts)? Instead of -15V, I am thinking of using -12V, will that be okay?
7. Any other things I should watch out for?

For my 3V ref, I've used a TL431 which is being fed by a LM7805 (without a heatsink - as I don't have any - feeding Vref and Vcc - is that a bad idea?), which in turn is connected to a 12V supply. I am thinking of driving this contraption with Raspberry Pi Pico.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Do I need hook up Io and the inverted (is there a better name for this
> pin?) Io to an op-amp for any meaningful use of BA9221?

No, but without the op amp 'meaningful' uses decline. The DAC is effectively a programmable current sink. However it is only guaranteed to be accurate when both outputs are held at ground potential. The op amp does that, as well as translating the current into a voltage.

> I have an LM358 (I have a few of these) - will that be adequate? If
> yes, how to hook it up, since the op-amp BA4558 isn't hooked to an
> external power supply?

Yes, you could use an LM358. Its gain-bandwidth product is a bit lower (0.7 MHz vs 3 MHz) but this may not bother you. Crossover distortion might be an issue at low output voltage (close to ground) but can be reduced using a pull-down resistor.

The op amp does need power supply connections. They aren't shown on the example circuit because it's assumed you know that.

> When I just connect Vcc (+5V) and Vref+ (3V) and Vref-, the voltage
> between Io and the inverted Io is shown as 10mV (holds steady). Why is
> that? When I measure the voltage between Io and the ground, it's
> showing around 1.2V. Similar thing with the inverted Io.

The output is a current sink going to the negative supply through NPN transistors. You won't get meaningful results measuring open-circuit voltage.

> In the application example provided, they used 3k resistors. Is that
> in order to limit the current fed into Vref pins (from the electrical
> characteristics table, we learn that Iref needs to be between 0.2 and
> 1.1 mA)?

The so-called Vref inputs actually set the DAC reference *current*. An internal op amp drives Vref(+) to Vref(-), which in this example produces 3 V / 3 kΩ = 1 mA. The 3 kΩ resistor between Vref(-) and ground just balances offset voltage on Vref(+) caused by bias current going through its 3 kΩ resistor.

> From the same electrical characteristics table, we see that logic
> input current is rated at 60 uA max. Does that mean I need to limit
> the current with adequately sized resistors feeding the digital pins?
> Or does that mean, that the IC will draw max 60uA per pin without the
> need to limit the current "externally"?

It just means the logic inputs won't draw more than 60 μA. Current limiting is not required when using standard logic levels.

> The example also calls for -15V but nowhere does it mention anything
> about +15V. Why would that be (for some reason, I am expecting a
> symmetry of sorts)? Instead of -15V, I am thinking of using -12V, will
> that be okay?

It doesn't need or want +15 V. Vcc is rated at +4.5 V to +5.5 V operating (+7 V absolute maximum). Vee is rated for -10.5 V min to -18 V max, -13.5 V to -16.5 V for specified accuracy. It should be OK on -12 V, possibly with slightly reduced accuracy.

Comment: What voltages should I power the LM358 with in this case? Can I use the same power supply (-12/+12V) I am using for the rest of the circuit? And what would be a better  choice for the op-amp here?

Comment: Yes, you can use +-12V. You need enough 'headroom' to account for output stage saturation, which on most non 'rail-to-rail' op amps is ~2V. So with +-12V supply you should be able to get up to +-10V output. Better op amps include the RC4558, LF353, TL072 and NE5532. Some interesting comparisons here  https://therepaircafe.wordpress.com/2021/03/20/in-defense-of-the-lm358/

Comment: Found a few NE5532s! Thank you (the link was interesting too). However, the circuit isn't producing an expected voltage on Vo of the op-amp. I am emulating a digital write with 3.3V to any of the digital (input) pins (accounting for the position in the "virtual" binary 12-bit value). Should the rest of the pins be pulled down? I am using 4.7k resistors on Vref(+) and Vref(-) (instead of the prescribed 3k ones). Ditto for the op-amp ones (the ones from the example are 5k ones). I don't reckon these values are way out of norm here - might they be?

Comment: _"Should the rest of the pins be pulled down?"_ - The datasheet isn't clear, but figure 5 suggests they should be (this is normal for TTL - inputs float high).

Comment: That moved me further along (getting larger, more meaningful values), however, the Vo is still off. For example, for 1000 0000 0000 on input, according to the datasheet, Vo should be -10.0000V. How would I go about troubleshooting this? For example, what should I expect on Io and the inverted Io pins (want to check the values before the op-amp stage)? Any other ideas?

Comment: _"according to the datasheet, Vo should be -10.0000V"_ - how did you calculate that?

Comment: In the table called "Code formats" (page 2, right below "Absolute maximum ratings" table) - a few binary input values are listed along with the expected Vo.

Comment: The DAC puts out a current and the op amp converts it to a voltage. To get the voltages specified you need to use the resistor values specified (or higher values proportional to them).